# Yii: How to disable a preloaded extension for a specific controller?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I use bootstrap extension in my Yii application. This extension is preloaded in the main config. There are some pages (for specific visitors) that don't need bootstrap. I want to disable this preloaded extension for this controller/actions.
 `WHy?`

1. Bootstrap related files have more than 100KB size and in my country this is huge!!!
2. I use [iview-master](http://iprodev.com/) slider and bootstrap has a conflict with it (when I remove bootstrap from preload it works fine)

A solution is removing bootstrap from preload and load it when needed. But the problem is just 5 percent of the pages don't need bootstrap. Actually I want to preload bootstrap and disable it in certain actions. `HOW?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove init line `bootstrap` from `preload` on your config, and use filter to load and restrict it on your controller. It could resolve your problem.
If most of your app use bootstrap, and you recognize updating most of them would be silly thing, just consider this solution if there has no way out.

[Toggle Bootstrap](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/434/load-the-yii-bootstrap-extension-on-specific-actions/).

Comment: I thank my GOD to find this solution. You sure there is no other way out?

Comment: I don't say that. I still hope someone else point out better solution. If they don't, you could have to use this althought it make you would spend more effort in current situation.

Comment: Thanks, Maybe I'll find better solution. Currently I used your helpful answer.